# How Can I check programmatically app store region/country?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, region, country

Is there a way to check it? 
I have an application URL, which I don't want to be opened expect if the user have a uk appstore. unfortunately, this application is available in many country, so when I put 'gb' on the link, it be redirected to the local region of the user.

Comment: Why do you want the link to only work if they are in the UK store?

Comment: You could do a CoreLocation check

Comment: @DustinRowland : the problem is that the app store region/country don't depend on the location .

Comment: @Dusting: You should not use CoreLocation because the user may have an account in a different country (e.g. when traveling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the in-app purchase [Store Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008300) to achieve this.

Request the product list using SKProductsRequest then check the returned SKProduct's priceLocale to see if the user's AppStore is the UK one.

Comment: What if there are no In-App Purchases in the app?

Answer (score 9):

For iOS 13+, check the `SKStoreFront` class. It has a `countryCode` that returns the country code belonging to the user's current App Store region.

**Swift**

```
if let storefront = SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront {
    print(storefront.countryCode) // Returns an Alpha-3 country code (USA, GBR etc.)
}
```

**Obj C**

```
[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].storefront.countryCode; // Returns an Alpha-3 country code (USA, GBR etc.)
```

You should be able to access the `SKStoreFront` instance by adding the StoreKit framework to your project, even if your app does not offer any purchases.

For more information, check out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront